# C# select all textboxes with certain CssClass

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to do server-side validation to make sure every textbox with a class of "required" is not blank. I can do this in jQuery no problem but not a pro yet with C#. Here's what I got:

```
protected void BtnCatering_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox.CssClass == "required" && TextBox.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill in required fields");
    }
}

<p>
    <label for="BookingName">Booking Name <span>*</span></label>
    <asp:TextBox class="inputText required" ID="BookingName" runat="server" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="ArrivaltDate">Arrival Date<span>*</span></label>
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="myDatepicker inputText required" id="ArrivaltDate" runat="server" />
</p
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be best prior to the submitting or posting to do Client Side Validation or is there a particular business rule that will not benefit in this particular situation..?

Comment: `MessageBox` is not used with ASP.NET

Comment: yep I'm doing client-side with jquery now doing server-side in case they have javascript turned off.

Comment: @mikhairu You can get MessageBox to work by adding a reference to Windows.Forms

Comment: @user1431633 It will pop up a message box on the server. No one will ever see this message box.

Comment: MessageBox on Web Forms is a bit unstable so why not use other alternatives for example ajax..or use some `Response.Write` perhaps and have big bold Red fonts display a message if there is an error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might be a solution for you:

```
var results = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(c =>
    Convert.ToString(c.Attributes["class"]).Contains("required"));
```

and then you could iterate through that result set. Maybe like this:

```
foreach (var tb in results)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
    {
        // do something here because this TextBox is empty
    }
}
```

However, the more correct approach is to probably use the [`RequiredFieldValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx) for each of those controls so that you can just call `this.Validate()` on the `Page` when you're ready, and then check `this.IsValid` on the `Page` and react to it.

Comment: I think you mean `Contains("required")`

Comment: +1 for this one. You could also just change it to `if ( this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x => x.CssClass.Contains("required") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Text)).Count() > 0 ) { // show message box }`

Comment: @TimBJames, yes, that is a nice optimization of that statement!

Answer (score 1):

For this reason ASP.NET has `Validation Controls` that you can use to validate data on server side (and optionally on client-side as well).

You could either use the `RequiredFieldValidator` control with each textbox or `CustomValidator` control.

See [MSDN: Types of Validation for ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwd43d0x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

For example, for the `TextBox` control with ID `BookingName` you can use the following.

`<asp:RequiredFieldValidator EnableClientScript="False" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
                        ControlToValidate="BookingName" runat="server" 
                        ErrorMessage="Please fill in this field"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>`

If you're using `Visual Studio` these controls are in your toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

try this way.

```
protected void BtnCatering_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (BookingName.Attributes["class"].ToString().Contains("required") && BookingName.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill in required fields");
    }
}
```

//`BookingName` is your textbox id.

Comment: CSS class parsing is more complicated than most people think. Good luck with `TextBox.CssClass += " notrequired";`

Comment: @zzzzBov, that's likely an edge-case that won't be seen here right? I mean the solution itself is very simple, I personally don't foresee any complexity like that.

Comment: There is no reason to choose `.Attributes["class"]` over `.CssClass`

Comment: What if I don't want to do it by an ID such as BookingName? I just want to look at all CssClass = "required" and where the value of those textboxes are blank. If I did it by ID, I'd have to replicate code for each id. DOes that make sense?

Comment: @TheSolution, it's straightforward for this case, but then suddenly someone's going to read this answer and assume it works for *all* cases, and then find that the code doesn't work as expected. [It's much safer to parse classes correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18318220/497418).

Answer (score 0):

The code is as simple as:

```
if (CssUtils.HasClass(TextBox.CssClass, "required") && TextBox.Text == "") {
    ..do stuff..
}
```

But this of course assumes that you have a valid `CssUtils` class that can accurately detect the presence of a class.

```
public static class CssUtils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-microsyntaxes.html#space-character
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly char[] WhitespaceCharacters = new[] { ' ', '\t', '\n', '\f', '\r' };

    /// <summary>
    /// ToggleAggregator toggles the <paramref name="parsedClass"/> within the <paramref name="current"/> classes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="current">
    /// A <see cref="String"/> of whitespace separated classes.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="parsedClass">
    /// A class to toggle within the <paramref name="current"/> classes.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="String"/> of resultant classes.
    /// </returns>
    private static string ToggleAggregator(string current, string parsedClass)
    {
        return HasClass(current, parsedClass)
                   ? RemoveClass(current, parsedClass)
                   : AddClass(current, parsedClass);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// AddClass adds the provided <paramref name="classes"/> to the <paramref name="source"/> classes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">
    /// A <see cref="String"/> of whitespace separated classes.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="classes">
    /// A <see cref="String"/> of whitespace separated classes to add to the <paramref name="source"/> classes.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="String"/> of merged classes.
    /// </returns>
    public static string AddClass(string source, string classes)
    {
        var sourceClasses = ParseClasses(source);
        var parsedClasses = ParseClasses(classes);
        var mergedClasses =
            sourceClasses
                .Union(parsedClasses)
                .ToArray()
                .Join(" ");
        return mergedClasses;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// AddClass adds the provided <paramref name="classes"/> to the <paramref name="source"/> classes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">
    /// A <see cref="String"/> of whitespace separated classes.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="classes">
    /// An <see cref="Array.string"/> of classes to add to the <paramref name="source"/> classes.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="String"/> of merged classes.
    /// </returns>
    public static string AddClass(string source, params string[] classes)
    {
        return AddClass(source, classes.Join(" "));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// HasClass checks whether all of the provided <paramref name="classes"/> are contained in the <paramref name="source"/> classes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">
    /// A <see cref="String"/> of whitespace separated classes.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="classes">
    /// A <see cref="String"/> of whitespace separated classes to check in the <paramref name="source"/> classes.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// <c>True</c> if all of the <paramref name="classes"/> are contained in the <paramref name="source"/> classes, <c>False</c> otherwise.
    /// </returns>
    public static bool HasClass(string source, string classes)
    {
        if (source.IsEmpty() || classes.IsEmpty()) return false;
        var sourceClasses = ParseClasses(source);
        var parsedClasses = ParseClasses(classes);
        return parsedClasses.Intersect(sourceClasses).Count() == parsedClasses.Count();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// RemoveClass removes the provided <paramref name="classes"/> from the <paramref name="source"/> classes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">
    /// A <see cref="String"/> of whitespace separated classes.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="classes">
    /// A <see cref="String"/> of whitespace separated classes to remove from the <paramref name="source"/> classes.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="String"/> of remaining classes.
    /// </returns>
    public static string RemoveClass(string source, string classes)
    {
        var sourceClasses = ParseClasses(source);
        var parsedClasses = ParseClasses(classes);
        var resultClasses =
            sourceClasses
                .Except(parsedClasses)
                .ToArray()
                .Join(" ");
        return resultClasses;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// RemoveClass removes the provided <paramref name="classes"/> from the <paramref name="source"/> classes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">
    /// A <see cref="String"/> of whitespace separated classes.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="classes">
    /// An <see cref="Array.string"/> of classes to remove from the <paramref name="source"/> classes.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="String"/> of remaining classes.
    /// </returns>
    public static string RemoveClass(string source, params string[] classes)
    {
        return RemoveClass(source, classes.Join(" "));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ToggleClass toggles the provided <paramref name="classes"/> within the <paramref name="source"/> classes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">
    /// A <see cref="String"/> of whitespace separated classes.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="classes">
    /// A <see cref="String"/> of whitespace separated classes to toggle within the <paramref name="source"/> classes.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="String"/> of resultant classes.
    /// </returns>
    public static string ToggleClass(string source, string classes)
    {
        var parsedClasses = ParseClasses(classes);
        return parsedClasses.Aggregate(source ?? "", ToggleAggregator);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ToggleClass toggles the provided <paramref name="classes"/> within the <paramref name="source"/> classes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">
    /// A <see cref="String"/> of whitespace separated classes.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="classes">
    /// An <see cref="Array.string"/> of classes to toggle within the <paramref name="source"/> classes.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="String"/> of resultant classes.
    /// </returns>
    public static string ToggleClass(string source, params string[] classes)
    {
        return ToggleClass(source, classes.Join(" "));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ToggleClass toggles the provided <paramref name="classes"/> within the <paramref name="source"/> classes dependant on the state of the <paramref name="switch"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">
    /// A <see cref="String"/> of whitespace separated classes.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="classes">
    /// A <see cref="String"/> of whitespace separated classes to toggle within the <paramref name="source"/> classes.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="switch">
    /// When <c>True</c>, the <paramref name="classes"/> will be added to the <paramref name="source"/> classes.
    /// When <c>False</c>, the <paramref name="classes"/> will be removed from the <paramref name="source"/> classes.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The <see cref="String"/> of resultant classes.
    /// </returns>
    public static string ToggleClass(string source, string classes, bool @switch)
    {
        return @switch ? AddClass(source, classes) : RemoveClass(source, classes);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ParseClasses splits the provided whitespace separated list of <paramref name="classes"/> into an array of distinct classes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="classes">
    /// A <see cref="String"/> of whitespace separated classes.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="Array.string"/> of distinct classes.
    /// </returns>
    public static string[] ParseClasses(string classes)
    {
        return (classes ?? "")
            .Split(WhitespaceCharacters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Distinct()
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```